# Why is readonly dropped from TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, readonly

```
interface I {
    readonly x: boolean
}
class C implements I {
    constructor(public x: boolean) {}
}
const c = new C(false);
c.x = true;
```

I'd expect that `tsc` would complain here that `C` doesn't implement `I` because `C.x` isn't `readonly`, or to complain that I can't set `c.x` because it's a `readonly` field.  What's the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a property definition looser in this regard, which is what's happened here. You've overridden the definition from `I` by using `public x: boolean` in your constructor parameter list. You've effectively written:

```typescript
interface I {
    readonly x: boolean
}
class C implements I {
    public x: boolean; // <=== Overriding declaration
    constructor(x: boolean) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
const c = new C(false);
c.x = true;
```

The `x` in `C` is not `readonly`, even though the `x` in `I` is, because the declaration in `C` overrides the one in `I`.

To fix it, I don't think you have a lot of choice other than to repeat it:

```typescript
interface I {
    readonly x: boolean
}
class C implements I {
    constructor(public readonly x: boolean) { }
    //                 ^^^^^^^^
}
const c = new C(false);
c.x = true; // Error now
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-JQRwAmA9iADYCeyAHgFzIBGZZlxIuAvrgpXADOg5AGFkwALYAHDpIjgR6bHgIIKgsFACuCMGSgAKaduaVgCQsXJVajFmw5wQASkzJeOT+pCbklgF5kEAgAdzFDeEpBCBcAbj4AOjpkIK1tCDjkAHps5ABRKCgDIA)

Comment: I wish I could find something in the documentation to point to on this. :-| I mean, why can you override `readonly` but not the type?